# Degree of a map which is not a path

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

We learned in our class about the map $deg: \pi_1(S^1,1) \to \mathbb{Z}$. Which works as follows:
take $\alpha$ lookat $1$ in $S^1$ take the unique lifting beginning at $0$ with respect to the standart covering map $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$ $x\mapsto e^{2\pi ix}$. then the Degree is the endpoint of the path.

Now we have the following lemma which says that $f:S^1\to S^1$ $z\to z^n $ has degree $n$. Now Im confused what is meant by this. $f$ is no loop at all as it is not defined on $I$. So how can we lift that? In the proof than he dont proof that $f$ has degree $n$ but that $g:I \to S^1$ $t\mapsto e^{2\pi nit}$ has degree $n$ which is clear but this are just different maps or what is meant here?

Can someone tell me how to understand this?

Comment: Any continuous image of $S^1$ is a loop.

Comment: intuitvly I understand this but how das this work formally. We defined a loop to be a continuos map $f: I \to X$ s.t $f(0)=f(1)$. Now a continuos image of $S^1$ is a set not such map right?

Comment: S1 can be defined as a quotient of I, by identifying 0 and 1. Thus, a map $f$ as you describe is equivalent to a map out of S1

Comment: It's standard to identify the continuous image of $S^1$ with the map $S^1\to X$. They refer to the same thing. Furthermore, $f\colon I \to X$ s.t. $f(0) = f(1)$ factors through a unique map $\overline f\colon S^1\to X$ for $S^1$ is simply the quotient space $I/{\sim}$ where $0\sim 1$.

Comment: @user1072285 loops $I\to X$ and continuous maps $S^1\to X$ are in one-to-one correspondence by composing with $I\to S^1$, $t\mapsto exp(2\pi i t)$. And so many authors freely interchange loops $I\to X$ with maps $S^1\to X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any topological space $X$ and any continuous function $f : S^1 \to X$ you get a loop $g : [0,1] \to X$ based at the point $f(1)$ by using the formula $g(t) = f(e^{2\pi i t})$.